# Failed to connect to a remote MySQL database via an Ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL database via an Ubuntu server using a command like:

```
mysql -u oooo -p -h ooo.ooo.oo.oo
```

Then it just returned:

```
mysql: unknown variable 'log=/var/log/mysql/logfile.log'
```

I've checked that the file 'logfile.log' does not exist and I have no idea what is the next step.

Comment: Put `-p` parameter at the end.

Comment: @i486 It does not working and return a same error message :(

Comment: check related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321800/mysql-unknown-variable-cant-run-any-mysql-applications-doesnt-seems-to-be-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search your machine for a file named my.cnf. That file will probably contain your offending variable. Comment it out.